# Cannot assign to property: 'selectedDealClosingDate' is a get-only property - SwiftUI

Tags: swift, string, date, core-data, swiftui

I'm using a DatePicker to store the selected date in Core Data in the format string and so I used a computed property that returns a String and uses a DateFormatter that accepts a type date to be converted in string.

I have another view which fetches the stored date of type string from CoreData.

So, to convert that string date to type Date to be fetched in the date picker I created a computed property that returns a type Date and using dateFormatter I convert the fetched date of type String to type Date.

The picker requires a Binding Date and I'm following MVVM so I've a ExistingDealDetailsViewModel from where I'm accessing dealClosingDate.

But the compiler gives me the Error:
"Cannot assign to property: 'selectedDealClosingDate' is a get-only property".

Requirement/Goal: I want to retrieve the stored date and display it in the DatePicker as the selected date.

All and any sort of help is appreciated, thank you.

ExistingDealsView:

```
         VStack {
            Text("Deal Closing Date")
                .foregroundColor(.gray)
                .frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading)
            
            DatePicker("Select a date:", selection: $existingDealDetailsVM.selectedDealClosingDate, displayedComponents: [.date]) //Error is shown at this line
                .padding()
                .overlay(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 0)
                            .stroke(lineWidth: 1)
                            .foregroundColor(.gray))
                .datePickerStyle(.compact)
        }
        .padding()
```

ExistingDealDetailsViewModel:

```
import SwiftUI

class ExistingDealDetailsViewModel: ObservableObject {

    @Published var toggle: Bool = false

    func update(){
        CoreDataManager.shared.save()
    }

    var deal = Deal() // Deal is a CoreData Entity Class 


    var dateFormatter = DateFormatter()

    var selectedDealClosingDate: Date {
        var dealClosingDate = deal.dealClosingDate //dealClosingDate is of type String
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd/MM/YY"
    
        return dateFormatter.date(from: dealClosingDate) ?? Date.now
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Think about what happens when the user changes the selection using the date picker - you would want `selectedDealClosingDate` to be set to the newly selected value, don't you? But look at the way you have declared `selectedDealClosingDate`! You've only defined how to compute its value, but not how to set its value.

```
var selectedDealClosingDate: Date {
    var dealClosingDate = deal.dealClosingDate
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd/MM/YY"

    return dateFormatter.date(from: dealClosingDate) ?? Date.now
}
```

You should add a setter:

```
var dateFormatter = {
    let formatter = DateFormatter()
    formatter = .dateFormat = "dd/MM/yy"
    formatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")
    return formatter
}()
var selectedDealClosingDate: Date {
    get {
        var dealClosingDate = deal.dealClosingDate
        return dateFormatter.date(from: dealClosingDate) ?? Date.now
    }
    set {
        deal.dealClosingDate = dateFormatter.string(from: newValue)
    }
}
```

Also, I find it a bit weird that you are storing a deal closing date in Core Data as a string. You might want to reconsider that.

Comment: How do I store the selected date as a Date? And how would I fetch it then?

Comment: @arifashraf I haven't used Core Data in a while, but doesn't Core Data support storing Dates? (IIRC)

Comment: 'CoreData' does support storing `Dates` directly.

Comment: Yes it does. I was able to store it in Date Format but its the fetching part which is the problem.

Comment: Yeah I'll do that

Comment: Fixed the problem. Stored and fetched the Date property from Core Data. Thanks for the Idea.